# Is there a way to count text in R from csv?

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv files containing species names from several different families and I am computing the Shannon index. The way that I am coding it on R makes me have to count each species from each family as number tally. Is there any way I can implement some code to give me a count of each species from each family?

I am not sure where to even start or if its even possible for R to do this. Any light on the situation would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my csv file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9e6mdu319a6071t/ALLdataCLEANED.csv?dl=0

Thanks!

Comment: see aggregate and/or tapply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this job in R.

```
dt<-read.csv("~/Downloads/ALLdataCLEANED.csv")
```

1.Base R

```
aggregate(latitude~family+sciname,data=dt, length)
```

2.Package `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, lapply(.SD, length), by=c("family", "sciname"), .SDcols="latitude"]
```

3.Package `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
  group_by (family, sciname) %>%
  summarise(n=length(latitude))
```

Comment: @poolshark Btw, I will recommend you to use `data.table` and `dplyr` as they are much faster thank base R.